# How to convert from Hex to Unicode?

Tags: c#, unicode

My application receives Hex values from client and converts back to character which is usually chinese character. But I can't implement this properly. As per my current programme it can convert "e5a682e4bd95313233" to "如何123" but I am actually receiving "59824F55003100320033" from the client side for the same Chinese character "如何123" and my programme unable to convert back into string. Please help me on this.

Here is my current code:

```
        byte[] uniMsg = null;
        string msg = "59824F55003100320033";
        uniMsg = StringToByteArray(msg.ToUpper());
        msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uniMsg);


        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
        {
          hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
          byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
          for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
          {
             raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
          }
          return raw;
        }
```

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Solution:

updated

```
  msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uniMsg);
```

to

```
 msg  = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(uniMsg)
```

Thanks to @CodesInChaos for suggesting the encoding type.

Comment: I'd rename `StringToByteArray` so the name mentions that it's using hex encoding. Perhaps `HexStringToByteArray` or simply `HexToBytes`.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be encoded in UTF8. Note the `00 31 00 32 00 33` part. In UTF8, it'd be just `31 32 33`. I think the hexstring is in UTF16 BE, because it's exactly 2 bytes per character and they are 00-padded. Decode your byte array as UTF16, you will get a string. Then you can use it as string, or reconvert it to any other encoding you need.

Comment: The most significant byte comes first, so it's big-endian. `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks a lot for suggesting Encoding.BigEndianUnicode. Now its working like a charm.